# Delete or Join adjacent vertices

Tags: qgis, polygon, merge, vertices

QGIS Zurich 3.18 Win10.
I need to trace and create one polygon from a large area by following actual field lines that do not follow straight lines. As panning and scrolling often triggers a completed polygon I am creating smaller adjacent polygons then selecting both and Merging. Before Merging I also use Edit Geometry, Vertex Tool to overlap the nearby polygon edges. Mostly it works but not always. Then, no matter how I move the vertices they do not overlap but remain as separate lines[image] So the merged Polygon has a line of vertices running through it where it should be one unified area. How do I delete or join up what should be coincident vertices?

with all others off and only the one polygon active, the polygon where I had first Edit/Geometry.Merge Selected resulting in this one polygon with these vertices. I have then used Vector Chk Geometries with this Error Result. [image] I changed the Set Error Resolutions but it appeared to have no effect and reverted back to default. You can see there are three extraneous vertices that I cannot select delete or move. So what do I do. Reverting back to Edit/Geometries/Vertex Tool I can see that there are is one part line (btwn vertices) doubled up with another extended line which duplicates part of this first line. But again I cannot select move delete any one item without deleting the whole polygon!

Comment: Are you using a three button mouse? I believe normally you can pan by holding middle mouse button and right click is to complete the feature. I just attempted it on my QGIS install to verify,

Comment: Yes three buttons,centre to pan, but going around a lot of small feature my figure strays enough to the right to initiate an unwanted click. As still trying to master QGIS features I have no confidence in making a series of smaller polygons then some how make the last polygon line become the same start line for a new polygon. Think the feature is there but just dont know how to use it. So I have to start all over again, so frustrating but at least I now know I have to watch the right button!